# CSSStyleDeclaration Error while rendering UI on angular6

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, angular6

[image: Can someone please help?]

Wherever on the html page [ngStyle]="selType[i]" (ngStyle refers to a function call), it is erroring out.The version of chrome being used is Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit).
The same piece of code was working a few days back. I am not sure what went wrong. I am new to angular libraries. Can someone please help?

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the content of `JoinSourceFilesComponent`?

Comment: Hi @nej_simon! somehow the html code is not getting uploaded.

Comment: Just updated the original question

Comment: Always give a stackblitz replica of your problem.

Comment: More information is needed, what is `selType[i]`? Upload the relevant part of the component source otherwise it's impossible to say what's wrong!